# Internet Explorer failing to show elements

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, compatibility

For some reason, my website ([find-minecraft-servers.com](http://find-minecraft-servers.com)) sometimes displays oddly in Internet Explorer. The number underneath Servers Listed in the green-ish banner sometimes fails to show altogether, like the image below, however when I check the source the number is in there, so it's not an error server-side.

This error is only occasional and appears on IE10. The site is using the Bootstrap framework. Here is the code for the Servers Listed and other statistics elements:

```
<div class="banner">
        <div class="container" style="background: transparent;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center whiteborder">
                    <h1>
                        <?php
                            // connect to mysql
                            require('includes/mysql.php');
                            $totalplayers = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(players) FROM servers WHERE suspended=0"));
                            echo number_format($totalplayers['SUM(players)']);
                        ?>
                    </h1>
                    <h3>PLAYERS ONLINE</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center whiteborder">
                    <h1>
                        <?php $totalservers = "SELECT * FROM servers WHERE verified=1 AND enabled=1 AND suspended=0"; echo number_format(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($totalservers)));?>
                    </h1>
                    <h3>SERVERS LISTED</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-center whiteborder">
                    <h1>
                        <?php echo number_format(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM votes")));?>
                    </h1>
                    <h3>TOTAL VOTES</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: SERVERS LISTED number not showing]

Comment: Use developer tools in IE (pressing F12), select that element and check the css, hope you can fix that way.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. However, using a `h1` tag for the numbers doesn't seem like a good idea. Semantically and for SEO.

Comment: What does the Document Object Model/ source code look like? Is: <div class="col-sm-4 text-center whiteborder"> <h1>SOME NUMBER HERE!!!</h1>   <h3>SERVERS LISTED</h3> </div> in the page that Internet Explorer has processed?

Comment: @mplungjan The number is generated by PHP, but as I said in the question the number is in the source code, so asking that is irrelevant.

Comment: @Duncan Yes, the number is in the source correctly

Comment: Not irrelevant. Perhaps you have other code that hides or removed the number using AJAX with an empty result

Comment: @mplungjan Okay I see where you're coming from, but no I have nothing like that it's just a simple PHP echo.

Comment: This question doesn't have any code and the link seems to be working fine on my side. Has the issue been fixed? If it has, delete it or add an answer; if not, add some relevant code to it, people shouldn't have to visit your site to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well seeing as the div that accompanies the `<h1>` also accompanies the `<h3>`, and you say that the h3 consistently displays; I'd hazard a guess and say that the problem lies exclusively with the CSS associated exclusively with the h1.

The only CSS that is directly associated with the h1 is

```
h1{margin:.67em 0;font-size:2em}
```

Now there isn't anything obviously wrong with this (and it validates fine) though is it possible that that 0 is triggering some strange quirk with IE?

Sticking the page through an IE6 emulator results in this:

[image: ie6 emulator]

Clearly broken - BUT the server number still displays.

FWIW font-size has been supported since IE 5.5.

So in summation: it is probably just you. If it isn't it is probably because some detail concerning the css (possibly that "0") has made IE go into a panic concerning the isolated set of rules, and do the equivalent of display:none. It is possible that there is some additional rule in your CSS doing odd things (the code isn't exactly setup well for maintainability). But I would say that that is unlikely.